# Fill or Kill EC2 Spot Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using EC2 API to request SPOT instances on EC2 - Code below works great on node.js.  The problem is that if the price is too low, the EC2 request will stay active and will be filled if the price drops below price set.  I know I can write my own logic to look for unfilled requests and kill them, but was wondering if there is a clean way to do this as part of the initial request.

`var SPOTRequest = {
            SpotPrice : price,
            InstanceCount : NumToLaunch,
            Type : "one-time",
            LaunchSpecification :sClient
    }`

```
ec2.client.requestSpotInstances(SPOTRequest,function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
          returnPackage.status = "ERROR:"+err;
          res.write(JSON.stringify(returnPackage)); 
          res.end();  
          console.log(err);

      }          
      else {
            returnPackage.status = "SUCCESS";
            res.write(JSON.stringify(returnPackage));
            res.end();
            console.log(data);
        }

});
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `ValidUntil` parameter to from the [requestSpotInstances()](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2_20130201.html#requestSpotInstances-property) method have your request auto-expire immediately if not filled within your desired time frame:

> ValidUntil — (Date)
>
> End date of the request.
>
> If this is a one-time request, the request remains active until all
>   instances launch, the request is canceled, or this date is reached. If
>   the request is persistent, it remains active until it is canceled or
>   this date and time is reached.